# Why are classes generated by EF Power Tools not partial?

Tags: entity-framework, code-generation, partial-classes

I'm using Reverse Engineered Code First code and see stubs like:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
        ...
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
...
}
```

[When, based on this question, i'd expect to see partial classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202016/why-poco-classes-generated-ef-4-x-dbcontext-generator-for-c-sharp-are-partial)

Wouldn't this change the preferred way of extending the generated classes with my own code (which is very nicely summarized in the linked answer, btw)?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our aim was to generate the simplest classes possible, as close to what you would write by hand as we could. There is no problem changing them to be partial - that's exactly the kind of reason we made the generation customizable.

~Rowan

Comment: Rowan, is it possible to query the extended properties from SQL Server?  I would like to decorate the classes like

///
/// <summary>
/// Description from SQL Server Extend Properties
/// </summary>
public string Example { get; set; }

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to customize the output of the entity objects by changing the TT files.

[Rowan Miller has an excellent blog post on how to do it.](http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/)

In your example, you can update the Entity.TT file that's int he template

From this:

```
public class <#= efHost.EntityType.Name #>
```

To this:

```
public partial class <#= efHost.EntityType.Name #>
```

and it will create the partial classes you're looking for.

Comment: I get the general theory of TT's usage but am looking to understand what looks like a conscious choice by the folks behind the Power Tools to not be partial.